# What is an example of an algorithm with complexity of O(n^5)?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

can anyone provide an example of an algorithm with minimal running time complexity of O(n^5)?

Comment: By the way, any linear `O(n)` algorithm is also `O(n^5)`.

Comment: ypercube is right, people confuse big O and big theta, which is probably what he meant

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O n5 volume algorithm for complex bodies.

http://matmod.elte.hu/~lovasz/vol5.pdf

Comment: +1 nice example. Did you know it from before or just googled it?

Comment: plead the fifth? :) Was curious from the question, happened to stumble upon a nice one.

Comment: I suppose you could say 3SAT or Traveling Salesman is at least O(n^5) as well :)  In any case, nice job...

Comment: Note this is O\*(n^5), which means there are `log n` factors that they have ignored.  Furthermore, the 'n' refers to the dimension, not the complexity of the body.  Also "convex" not "complex".  The algorithm assumes a "separation oracle" which lets one test if points are in the body for free and if not, gives you a separating plane...if you're not familiar with the field you probably wouldn't assume all this from the description "O(n^5) volume algorithm"

Answer (score 4):

```
for 1 to n
 for 1 to n
  for 1 to n
   for 1 to n
    for 1 to n
     Do Something
```

Comment: No, n should be the input size. And it should be minimal

Comment: so, change the for loops to "foreach n".  Do Something could be return the 5-wide tuple, this would be a minimal method to return all 5-wide tuples of the set of n objects.

Answer (score 4):

```
void N5(int n)
{
    for( int n1 = 0; n1 < n; n1++ )
    {
        for( int n2 = 0; n2 < n; n2++ )
        {
            for( int n3 = 0; n3 < n; n3++ )
            {
                for( int n4 = 0; n4 < n; n4++ )
                {
                    for( int n5 = 0; n5 < n; n5++ )
                    {
                        DoSomething();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Integral transformation:
http://vergil.chemistry.gatech.edu/resources/programming/mp2-transform-project.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Finden and Gordon's algorithm on [Obtaining common pruned trees](http://www.springerlink.com/content/r27779vw53487483/) runs in O(n^5)

Answer (score 1):

Convex hull in 10 dimensions has been proven to require O(n^5) (the proof was for general d, showing that the hull can be O(n^floor(d/2)) in the worst case, IIRC)